# Select cells within range in table after dragging with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a straightforward way to select cells in a table. Selecting is determined by the start and end point of dragging with a mouse, similar to how it works in Excel.

My current solution works as long as you drag from left to right and top to bottom. I tried to counter this by sorting the coordinates but that did not help. Instead, now always two cells are selected in the direction you are dragging in (horizontal or vertical). I can't seem to figure out why.

The main idea is:

- onmousedown: store starting cell's coordinates by using row and cell idnex
- onmouseover/onmouseleave: store ending cell's coordinates
- On every event, slice down the rows and their children to get the correct range as given by the coordinates

I feel like I am making a thinking error but I do'nt see which one.

```js
function markSelection(selection) {
  // Sort coordinates (start-end point) numerically
  selection["x"] = selection["x"].sort(sortNumbers);
  selection["y"] = selection["y"].sort(sortNumbers);

  // Only get relevant rows within range
  const rows = $("#pixels>tbody tr").slice(selection["y"][0], selection["y"][1] + 1);
  $("#pixels>tbody tr td").removeClass("selected");
  let cells = $();
  // In each relevant row, get the relevant cells
  rows.each(function(i, el) {
    cells = cells.add($(el).children("td").slice(selection["x"][0], selection["x"][1] + 1));
  });
  cells.addClass("selected");
}

function sortNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

let isDragging = false;
let selection = {};

$("#pixels").on("mousedown", "td", function() {
  // Start dragging
  isDragging = true;

  const $this = $(this);
  selection["x"] = [$this.index(), $this.index()];
  selection["y"] = [$this.parent("tr").index(), $this.parent("tr").index()];
  markSelection(selection);
}).on("mouseover", "td", function() {
  if (isDragging) {
    const $this = $(this);
    selection["x"][1] = $this.index();
    selection["y"][1] = $this.parent("tr").index();
    markSelection(selection);
  }
}).on("mouseup", "td", function() {
  // End dragging
  isDragging = false;

  const $this = $(this);
  selection["x"][1] = $this.index();
  selection["y"][1] = $this.parent("tr").index();
  markSelection(selection);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  // End dragging
  isDragging = false;
});
```

```css
#pixels {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#pixels td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

#pixels td.selected {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pixels">
  <tbody style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix is to make copies of your coordinate arrays before sorting and sort the copies and use copy results to slice rows and cells .

Another would be use Math.max & Math.min to get start/end instead of sorting

Sorting of the original arrays is what is causing problem by switching start and end points when move is upwards or to the left

```js
function markSelection(selection) {
  // make copies before sorting
  const coords = {
    x: selection["x"].slice().sort(sortNumbers),
    y: selection["y"].slice().sort(sortNumbers)
  }
  // Only get relevant rows within range
  const rows = $("#pixels>tbody tr").slice(coords["y"][0], coords["y"][1] + 1);
  $("#pixels>tbody tr td").removeClass("selected");
  let cells = $();
  // In each relevant row, get the relevant cells
  rows.each(function(i, el) {
    cells = cells.add($(el).children("td").slice(coords["x"][0], coords["x"][1] + 1));
  });
  cells.addClass("selected");
}

function sortNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

let isDragging = false;
let selection = {};

$("#pixels").on("mousedown", "td", function() {
  // Start dragging
  isDragging = true;

  const $this = $(this);
  selection["x"] = [$this.index(), $this.index()];
  selection["y"] = [$this.parent("tr").index(), $this.parent("tr").index()];
  markSelection(selection);
}).on("mouseover", "td", function() {
  if (isDragging) {
    const $this = $(this);
    selection["x"][1] = $this.index();
    selection["y"][1] = $this.parent("tr").index();
    markSelection(selection);
  }
}).on("mouseup", "td", function() {
  // End dragging
  isDragging = false;

  const $this = $(this);
  selection["x"][1] = $this.index();
  selection["y"][1] = $this.parent("tr").index();
  markSelection(selection);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  // End dragging
  isDragging = false;
});
```

```css
#pixels {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#pixels td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

#pixels td.selected {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pixels">
  <tbody style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
      <td style="border-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am very confused. I don't see what the difference is? I mean, I don't understand why we need copies? What goes wrong if we don't have copies?

Comment: Because `sort()` mutates original array but you always modify the same indexes in each array. So what was the start becomes the end

Comment: Think of it this way `x=[8,7]`. Then sort becomes `x=[7,8]`. Now move to next cell left it becomes `x=[7,6]`. You lost start at 8

Comment: Aah yes, makes sense! Thanks! `slice()` without arguments copies the array? Or what does it do exactly?

Comment: Copies whole array to new array